# I have an ESP 32 CAM and I need to send the live streaming of the cam to the cloud for object detection YOLO v8 model how can I do it?

Tags: image-processing, esp32, live-streaming, arduino-esp32, yolov8

I'm currently working on project where I install a camera (ESP 32 CAM) on to the cart and I've written the code for object detection. Whenever someone puts something in the cart it'll automatically detects the item and reflects in the virtual cart (APP). So now I need to send the live stream data from the ESP 32 CAM to the cloud to run the model. How can i do it >

I tried of AMAZOM KINESIS but its not what I thought of.